# Accessing the result from website in windows class library in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having my partner website(App1) which is hosted in IIS. It has a menu called SummaryReport (xxx.aspx)

In App1,the SummaryReport page contains Date calendar and Go button. When clicking that Go, the result set for the selected date will be displayed in the same page using display controls like DataGrid or gridview something.

Actually I am creating a class library in c# for another application(App2). Now my aim is to get the result set from the xxx.aspx(App1) in my library and I will do further manipulation with result set data in my App2. I don't know how to get the result set from App1 in App2. The only input I am having is URL of xxx.aspx page(App1 URL).

(eg: http://x.x.x.x/SampleWebsite/xxx.aspx)

Kindly anyone provide me the idea to achieve this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest placing the processing logic that lives in App1 into the class library, which you can then call from the same class library as well as call it from App1 and you can do what you want with the result set in both places.